# Flash scaling quality

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scaling

I have a flash application in which I need to scale a MovieClip.  This MovieClip contains an image (in a Loader) with a resolution of 1024x768 (which is the size of the MovieClip as well).

When I want to scale this MovieClip to 80% I do:

```
myMovieClip.scaleX = 0.8;
myMovieClip.scaleY = 0.8;
```

The problem is the resulting scaled image has aliasing and is not of good quality.  Is there a way to change the scaling algorithm used to get a better image?  Or is there a better way to scale MovieClips?

I can't rely on bitmap data because this MovieClip may contain another SWF with video for example and it must scale regardless of its internal content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the [smoothing property on your Bitmap](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#smoothing) before you scale it (or its container). Also see this link: [Bitmap.smoothing - how to reduce image distortion](http://www.flepstudio.org/forum/tutorials/419-bitmap-smoothing-how-reduce-image-distortion.html).

Comment: Thanks, the solution provided in your second link did the trick.

Comment: 2nd link is now dead.

Comment: Is there any way to enable this globally for all bitmaps?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the accepted answer but probably the missing second link is this one:
[Bitmap.smoothing - how to reduce image distortion](http://flex-spot.blogspot.com/2010/05/bitmapsmoothing-how-to-reduce-image.html)

From the link: To reduce distortion when resizing a Bitmap, if it's an image loaded externally:

```
var image:Bitmap=loader.content as Bitmap;
image.smoothing=true;
```

If it's an Bitmap from the library, just check its property "Allow smoothing"